# How to fetch only words from text in mysql in loop?

Tags: mysql

I have a table named posts which have 3 fields : id,user,posts
I want to retrieve only the words beginning with @ ,
for example my text in post field is "thank you @mark and @ali and @isac for your good job",
how can fetch only @mark @ali  @isac ?
thanks

Comment: This will probably have to be done in a stored procedure, because you can't do arbitrary loops in SQL.

Comment: Are you processing the data using a programming language like PHP or Python? It would be much easier to do this in those languages using regular expressions.

Comment: Ill make the loop with php ...

Comment: Then that's where you should extract the words: `preg_match_all('/@\w+/', $posts, $matches)`

Comment: What kind of programmer are you if that comment was enough to get you 99% of the way there?

Comment: I think my question is not clear !

Comment: Stepping back for a moment from @Barmar's entirely correct answer that extracting the names is much better done in your php code using regular expressions, you could also consider using that same regular expression BEFORE you save the data, and create a separate table linking @-names to posts. That would be very useful to help write an efficient query to answer "what are all the posts that mention ali"? It really depends on what questions you need to answer.